# Inline-block expand height parent container

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div elements side by side that are set as inline-block. They both reside within a containing div. I have set the right div to height 100% but because the height of the containing div is dynamic it won't expand. Does anyone know how to make the right hand div (coulmn) expand to the dynamic height of the containing div?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left_column">Dynamic Content In Here</div>
<div class="right_column">Side bar to expand to the height of the containing div</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Oliver

Comment: Hi the issue is with the height of the containing div being dynamic. The idea is for content in the left hand div to push the containing div down. With no height attribute set the right hand div won't expand to the dynamic height of the containing div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you search something like this:

```
.container {
    min-height: 700px;
}

.right_column {
    min-height: inherit;
}
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssuS6/1/).

Answer (score 3):

After having some issues with the same problem, the simplest solution is, in my opinion, to use `table-cell` as the display property. It works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
html, body
{
  height:100%;
}

#container
{
 min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I have a min-height of 700px set to the container but the height of 100% on the inline-block divs is being ignored

Comment: If I set height 700px it works, if I set min-height it is ignored.